# Javascript append onblur.value mysql

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I trying to get the value of an `input type="text"` and with it, check if it really exists at my database and, if true, append it with an `input type="hidden" value="value-of-last-input"`, but my code isn't working.

Here:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="codigo" name="codigo" onblur="RetirarProduto(this)" />
```

and JS:

```js
function RetirarProduto(campo) {
    var codigo = campo.value;
    alert(codigo);
});
```

I used `alert` to check the value, but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function has one extra parenthesis at the end. Change your JavaScript to:

```
function RetirarProduto(campo) {
var codigo = campo.value;
alert(codigo);
}
```

And this should work. [Here is a working JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/5r1nr8tr/) Let me know if I can help any further :)

Comment: Worked the first part, my bad! haha!

Now, what should I do to check my db with the value and append a input hidden with label?

Comment: @GabrielSilva you should check about ajax functionaliites

Comment: That is quite a loaded question! I agree with Lelio, though. I would read up on your AJAX calls. JQuery has a much nicer way of doing this than JavaScript alone. Here's a link to read up on JQuery's AJAX: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Tried with ajax but I Don't know how to send the value to php to check db. 

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1onfgwrk/

Comment: Here is some example of how to use AJAX. I'm not sure if this code will run, as I am only using JSFiddle. However, hopefully you can get a good start from this! https://jsfiddle.net/1onfgwrk/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the value in the input form field. Then you can pass the value to your function and do whatever you need with it. Put this inside your input element.

onblur="var c = this.value; alert(c);"